# Getting Error: NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object After pressing play game on unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get these errors when I try to play my 2D game on unity the game works but I get these errors:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object Inventory..ctor () (at Assets/Scripts/Inventory.cs:13)
>
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object Inventory..ctor () (at Assets/Scripts/Inventory.cs:13)

This are the script I'm using that contains the problem :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{

    private List<Item> itemList;

    public Inventory()
    {

        CustonGameEvent.GameEvents.gameEvents.onItemPurchase += AddItem;

        itemList = new List<Item>();

        Debug.Log("Inventory");
    }

    public void AddItem(Item item)
    {
        itemList.Add(item);
    }
}
```

And this is the script that I'm using that has the `Null` line:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace CustonGameEvent
{
    public class GameEvents : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static GameEvents gameEvents;

        private void Awake()
        {
            gameEvents = this;
        }

        public event Action<Item> onItemPurchase;

        public void ItemPurchaseMade(Item ItemID)
        {
            if (onItemPurchase != null)
            {
                onItemPurchase(ItemID);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a partial solution, but you should try initializing `itemList` before assigning `AddItem` as the delegate to the `onItemPurchase` event. This is because the `AddItem` function tries to add an item to the `itemList`, which may not be initialized yet.

```
    public Inventory()
    {
        itemList = new List<Item>();

        CustonGameEvent.GameEvents.gameEvents.onItemPurchase += AddItem;

        Debug.Log("Inventory");
    }
```

Also note what Hamid Yusifli said, using a constructor on a Monobehaviour will have unintended consequences, such as the contructor being called multiple times instead of once. For example, if you run this code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ConstructorTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public ConstructorTest() {
        Debug.Log ("Constructor is called");
    }

    void Awake () {
        Debug.Log ("Awake is called");
    }

    void Start () {
        Debug.Log ("Start is called");
    }

    void Update () {        
    }
}
```

It will print out this:

```
Constructor is called
Constructor is called
Awake is called
Start is called
```

The constructor is called twice which may mess up your code depending on what it contains.

Comment: yeah still get the same problem even when there is nothing wrong with the code. kinda weird to me like everything is working fine but still get that error even when I used your order of the script. thank you though :D

Answer (score 2):

Don't use constructors to initialize **MonoBehaviour**. 
**MonoBehaviours** should be initialized with special methods called `Awake` or `Start`, otherwise you may see unexpected results.

Comment: yeah but i wanted to assign it to my inventory menu in-game and I can't assign it if it is not derived from a MonoBehaviour.